# Problem deleting head node in a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a doubly linked list in C. While coding it up, I ran into an issue when trying to delete the first element of the list.

Here is is a toy example that illustrates the problem:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct Node{
     struct Node * next;
     struct Node * previous;
     int data;
 }Node;


 Node* create_dll(int array[], int arrSize){
     Node *current = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
     current->next = NULL;
     current->data = array[0];
     for(int i = 1; i < arrSize; i++){
         Node *temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
         temp->data = array[i];
         temp->next = current;
         current->previous  = temp;
         current = temp;
     }
     current->previous = NULL; 
     return current;
 }
 void print_dll(Node *head){
     if(head != NULL){
         Node *current = head;
         while(current!=NULL){
         printf("%d \t", current ->data);
             current = current->next;
         }
     }
     puts(" ");
 }

 void delete_head(Node *head){
     Node *current = head;
     head = head->next;
     //head ->previous = NULL;
     free(current);
 }
 void kill(Node *head){
     Node *current = head;
     while (current != NULL){
         Node *previous = current;
         current = current ->next;
         free(previous);
     }
 }

 int main(){
     int array [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     int arrSize = 5;

     Node *head;

     head = create_dll(array, 5);

     print_dll(head);

     delete_head(head);
     print_dll(head);

     kill(head);
     return 0;

}
```

Whenever I try to run the code in main, which creates a DLL, then prints what's in it, then attempts to delete the first node, then print the list again, I get the following result:

```
    5   4   3   2   1    
    5
```

Now, I know that one fix would be to make `head` a global variable, but that will be problematic in other sections of the code, plus I don't really want to go that route. I also don't want to modify any of the function headers, or anything in the main.

I did get this to work by implementing the DLL with a dummy node that `head` always points to, but I"m sure there is a simple fix to this implementation that avoids all this.

Basically, if I can change what `head` points to in the `delete_head` function
and have this change be reflected in the main function, that would be a solution. Otherwise, I would be happy just to understand why this code fails to do what I want.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call delete_head, C parameter passing is by value, so head isn't changed on return.  You need to implement it like this:

```
void delete_head(Node **head){
            Node *current = *head;
            *head = current->next;
            //head ->previous = NULL;
            free(current);
}
```

And call it like this: `delete_head(&head);`

Comment: So I understand that to call the function like I did, I should not have expected there to be any change to the `head` variable in the main function, since to do so, I would have to pass a reference to `head`, which is itself a reference to the first node in the dll. Is this correct? Also, thanks for the solution, but I asked if there is a way to correct the problem I have without modifying the function headers. I guess there is no other way to solve issue without changing the signature of the functions, except  to use a dummy node?

Comment: alternatively, you could change delete_head to return a `Node *`, and have the return value be the updated value of head.

Comment: I thought of that, but that would involve changing the signature of one of the functions, and I wondered if it was possible to fix the issue without doing that.

Comment: @P.Gillich Yes it is possibly,  without changing, the **4** function headers. Further,  code does not need a DLL for those 4 functions as  a single link will do.  Notice the 4 functions never use the unnecessary `.previous` member.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is, all the external pointers are pointing to *individual nodes*. So when you cut the head off from the rest of the list, all the pointers to `head` keep pointing to it—you get the single node on its own, not the rest of the list.

I would solve this by adding an additional struct.

```
typedef struct DLL{
    struct Node * head;
} DLL;
```

When you want to create the list, create a `DLL` pointing to the head, instead of returning the head itself. Now when you want to change the head, change the pointer inside the `DLL` struct. All the references to the `DLL` itself can stay the same, but now the `head` inside it has changed, and all those references will see the new `head` when they look for it!

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understand better now why my implementation was flawed. Since your answer entails modifying presumably the main function, since I would have to create a `struct DLL` there, does that mean there is no other way to fix this code except by implementing a dummy node?